# Webpack, gulp and frontstreet framework in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, gulp

I try to add https://github.com/themeblvd/frontstreet frontstreet framework to Wordpress.

I have pre-built asset "frontstreet.js" in wp-content/themes/front-theme/js/frontstreet.js
In the same localization I put my custom "scripts.js" file to import modules. For test I type alert

```
import $ from 'jquery';

alert("test");
```

I run the site by gulp watch and it is working properly, with framework CSS classes. But no alert and console don't show any error. I think gulp doesn't see my "scripts.js" file.

**EDIT** In terminal I have error:

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './wp-content/themes/front-theme/js/scritps.js' in '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/front'

Gulp settings:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
settings = require('./settings'),
webpack = require('webpack'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
rgba = require('postcss-hexrgba'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
mixins = require('postcss-mixins'),
colorFunctions = require('postcss-color-function');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'css/style.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, mixins, cssvars, nested, rgba, colorFunctions, autoprefixer]))
    .on('error', (error) => console.log(error.toString()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.themeLocation));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
  webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    }

    console.log(stats.toString());
    callback();
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    proxy: settings.urlToPreview,
    ghostMode: false
  });

  gulp.watch('./**/*.php', function(cb) {
    browserSync.reload();
    cb()
  });
  gulp.watch(settings.themeLocation + 'css/**/*.css', gulp.parallel('waitForStyles'));
  gulp.watch([settings.themeLocation + 'js/src/js/blocks/*.js', settings.themeLocation + 'js/scripts.js'], gulp.parallel('waitForScripts'));
});

gulp.task('waitForStyles', gulp.series('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'style.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()).pipe(browserSync.reload());
}))

gulp.task('waitForScripts', gulp.series('scripts', function(cb) {
  browserSync.reload();
  cb()
}))
```

Webpack config

```
const path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App: settings.themeLocation + "js/scritps.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js"),
    filename: "frontstreet.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  mode: 'development'
}
```

settings file

```
exports.themeLocation = './wp-content/themes/front-theme/';
exports.urlToPreview = 'http://localhost:8888/front/';
```

this is my Wordpress functions.php

```
// add frontstreet pre-built
    wp_enqueue_script('frontstreet-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/frontstreet.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My mistake but now I understand how it works.

That was messy

I had old pre-built file in the same folder where gulp had output for generate file. 
In gulp watch line I had src to framework blocks.